# Best $K$ such that $(u^2-4vw)^2>K(2v^2-uw)(2w^2-uv)$ for all positive $u,v,w$ with $u^2>4vw$, 2003 Hong Kong Mathematical Olympiad question 1

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math

> Find the greatest real number $K$ such that for all positive numbers $u,v,w$ with $u^2>4vw$ we have
> $$(u^2-4vw)^2>K(2v^2-uw)(2w^2-uv).$$

I initially thought that $K=0$ at max because I imagined that since $u^2>4vw$ means $(u^2-4vw)^2>0$ so the maximum of the LHS of the inequality must be $0$. But then this obviously does not make sense and I am stumped.

I'm kind of lost on what to do right now. I have tried multiple solutions in vain. At this point I'm about to give up but I do want to give one more attempt so any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Please post searchable MathJax question... not an unsearchable image.

Comment: @Yeonsu Na Show me, what exactly you had tried?

Comment: @YeonsuNa we will need you to show some working of your approaches

Comment: For example, what can you do, if you assume $w=1/v$?

Comment: I initially thought that K=0 at max because I imagined that since u^2>4vw, this means that (u^2-4vw)^2>0 so the maximum of the LHS of the inequality must be 0. But then this obviously does not make sense and I am stumped.

Comment: @YeonsuNa Please learn from what I have done to improve your question.

Answer (score 3):

A simple observation is both sides of
$$(u^2-4vw)^2>K(2v^2-uw)(2w^2-uv)$$
are **homogeneous** polynomial of the same degree, where $K$ is considered as a constant.

That means the inequality holds if and only if it holds when we replace $(u,v,w)$ by $(2u,2v,2w)$. Or by $(\frac u{2023}, \frac v{2023}, \frac w{2023})$. Or by $(1, \frac vu, \frac wu)$. Etc.

Both sides of the condition $u^2>4vw$ are also homogeneous polynomial of the same degree. Once again, the condition holds if and only if it holds when we replace $(u,v,w)$ by $(2u,2v,2w)$. Or by $(\frac u{2023}, \frac v{2023}, \frac w{2023})$. Or by $(1, \frac vu, \frac wu)$. Etc.

Instead of $2$, $\frac1{2023}$, $\frac1u$, a judicious factor can be selected. As Jyrki Lahtonen advised, we can choose a factor so that $vw$ becomes $1$, which should simplify the condition and the target inequality the most. That is, we can replace $(u,v,w)$ by $(\frac u{\sqrt{vw}}, \frac v{\sqrt{vw}}, \frac w{\sqrt{vw}})$. In other words, we can assume $vw=1$ without loss of generality! Now the problem is simplified to the following one.

> Find the greatest real number $K$ such that for all positive numbers $u, v$ with $u>2$ we have
> $$(u^2-4)^2>K(2v^2-\frac uv)(\frac2{v^2}-uv).$$

---

$$\begin{aligned}&(u^2-4)^2>K(2v^2-\frac uv)(\frac2{v^2}-uv)\color{#d0d0d0}{\quad\text{for all }u>2, v>0}\\
\iff &(u^2-4)^2>K(u^2-(v^3+\frac1{v^3})2u+4)\color{#d0d0d0}{\quad\text{for all }u>2, v>0}\\ 
\iff &(u^2-4)^2>K(u^2-2\cdot 2u+4)\color{#d0d0d0}{\quad\text{for all }u>2}\\ 
\iff &(u^2-4)^2>K(u-2)^2\color{#d0d0d0}{\quad\text{for all }u>2}\\ 
\iff &(u+2)^2>K\color{#d0d0d0}{\quad\text{for all }u>2}\\
\iff &16>K\\ 
\end{aligned}$$
where we use the fact $v^3+\frac1{v^3}\ge2$ with the equality holds for $v=1$, which is implied by AM-GM immediately.

Hence the greatest real number $K$ is $16$.

Comment: Why do we want to set $vw=1$? Because $vw$ appears the most in the condition and the target equality. Setting $vw$ to the simplest constant should help the most.

Comment: Or we can replace $(u,v,w)$ with $u^2>4vw$ by $(2, v,w)$ with $1>vw$.

Comment: (+1) This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Nice. (+1) If we don't do homogenization: We have $$(2v^2 - uw)(2w^2-uv)=4v^2w^2 + u^2 vw - 2u(v^3 + w^3) \le 4v^2w^2 + u^2 vw - 2u\cdot 2\sqrt{v^3w^3} = vw(u - 2\sqrt{vw})^2.$$ Thus, $(u^2 - 4vw)^2 \ge Kvw(u-2\sqrt{vw})^2$. Perhaps it will be shorter.